# Making a dynamic VBA autofill range

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I have some VBA code to auto fill the formulas in columns AE:AH whenever more data is posted into the sheet.  I am attempting to future proof it and make the range more dynamic in case we were to add more formulas.  Here is the current code.

```
Sheets(twtsumsheet).Select
usedRows1 = Worksheets(twtsumsheet).Cells(Worksheets(twtsumsheet).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("AE2:AH2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets(twtsumsheet).Range(Cells(2, 31), Cells(usedRows1, 34)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

So for example, currently formulas are in columns AE:AH.  Let's say we were to add one more to get another calculation off the data, so now we have formulas in columns AE:AI.  My macro would continue to just autofill the formulas in AE:AH due to this "Range("AE2:AH2").Select" and this "Cells(2, 31), Cells(usedRows1, 34)"

I'm new to VBA coding so I'm not getting any good ideas for it.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you already use a method to locate the last row, why not leverage that to find the last column, Hint `xltoLeft`?

Comment: ^^https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My **OCD** forces me to "clean" this code a bit...

Following @Scott Craner advice to look for last column with data.

**Note**: you should stay away from using `Select`.

```
With Sheets(twtsumsheet)
    usedRows1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    usedCols1 = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' get the last column

    With .Range(.Cells(2, 31),.Cells(2, usedCols1))
        .AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(2, 31), .Cells(usedRows1, usedCols1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With
End With
```

Comment: @ScottCraner yep, true that :)

Comment: This code combined with using .filldown from Jeeped is exactly what I needed.  Someone else wrote the code for the usedRows variable and I guess I didn't fully understand it until now.  I appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 2):

I honestly do not understand why so many people use .AutoFill when .FillDown or FillRight is more appropriate.

```
with Sheets(twtsumsheet)
    usedRows1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    usedCols1 = .Cells(2, .columns.count).End(xltoleft).column
    .Range(.Cells(2, 31), .Cells(usedRows1, usedCols1)).filldown
end with
```

Comment: Very helpful.  Thank you!